# How do I split a string with space after 30 array in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, regex, split

**Data Input :**

```
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy,aaaaa,2,0,High Max,22322,1212123,121212,121212,0,121212,0,121212,0,0,0,0,121212,0,0,121212,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet ,aaaaa,2,0,Low Min ,22322,1212123,121212,121212,0,121212,0,121212,0,0,0,0,121212,0,0,121212,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
Mauris vestibulum leo id turpis imperdiet,aaaaa,2,0,High Min,22322,1212123,121212,121212,0,121212,0,121212,0,0,0,0,121212,0,0,121212,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
```

**HTML :**

```
<input id="data_input"></input>
```

**JAVASCRIPT :**

```
var string= $("#data_input").val();
var newstring= string.split(/[ ,]+/);
```

**Output (But Wrong):**

```
"Lorem", "Ipsum", "is", "simply", "dummy", "aaaaa", "2", "0", "High", "22322", "1212123", "121212", "121212", "0", "121212", "0", "121212", "0", "0", "0", "0", "121212", "0", "0", "121212", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "Lorem", "ipsum", "dolor", "sit", "amet", "aaaaa", "2", "0", "Low", "22322", "1212123", "121212", "121212", "0", "121212", "0", "121212", "0", "0", "0", "0", "121212", "0", "0", "121212", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "Mauris", "vestibulum", "leo", "id", "turpis", "imperdiet", "aaaaa", "2", "0", "High","Max", "22322", "1212123", "121212", "121212", "0", "121212", "0", "121212", "0", "0", "0", "0", "121212", "0", "0", "121212", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", …
```

**Needed Output :**

```
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy,aaaaa,2,0,High Max,22322,1212123,121212,121212,0,121212,0,121212,0,0,0,0,121212,0,0,121212,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet ,aaaaa,2,0,Low Min,22322,1212123,121212,121212,0,121212,0,121212,0,0,0,0,121212,0,0,121212,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,Mauris vestibulum leo id turpis imperdiet,aaaaa,2,0,High Min,22322,1212123,121212,121212,0,121212,0,121212,0,0,0,0,121212,0,0,121212,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
```

Split adds comma at every white space it finds in the string Need to get comma after 30 length 
which is after 0 and before Lorem ipsum http://prntscr.com/pzr0lt And it got lot of lines like that N number of lines input

Comment: So you want all N lines to be combined into one line?

Comment: I have no idea what you actually want here. Please add a proper, verbal explanation of what you need to achieve.

Comment: Your output is all on one line, what happens if there's more than 30 items?

Comment: @Luke Yes i want it to get in 1 line so that i can splice it later in 30

Comment: @04FS Well i have a data string which i input and send it to var string which stores the value and var newstring split the string and adds comma after every 30 words(data) if you see screenshot i have highlighted when it has the end of the line.

Comment: @Luke if it has more than 30 items in that array string it will store it 1 string for now and then it will be spliced with the help of chuk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var string = $("#data_input").val();
var newstring = string.split(/\s?,|\n/g); // this is actually an array
$('#data_output').text(newstring.join(','))
```

```css
textarea {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
}

div {
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow-x: scroll;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea id="data_input">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy,aaaaa,2,0,High Max,22322,1212123,121212,121212,0,121212,0,121212,0,0,0,0,121212,0,0,121212,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet ,aaaaa,2,0,Low Min ,22322,1212123,121212,121212,0,121212,0,121212,0,0,0,0,121212,0,0,121212,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
Mauris vestibulum leo id turpis imperdiet,aaaaa,2,0,High Min,22322,1212123,121212,121212,0,121212,0,121212,0,0,0,0,121212,0,0,121212,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0</textarea>

Result
<div id="data_output"></div>
```

Comment: $('#data_output').text(newstring.join(',')) how can i type this in string ? Instead of appending or sending in data_output . Like var newdatastring = newdtring.join(';');

Comment: `var _array = string.split(/\s?,|\n/g);` `var _string = _array.join(',')`

Comment: Why is thst _array & _string used like that ? Just can't use var array / var string ?

Comment: You can, but you shouldnt: https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/javascript-identifiers

Answer (score 0):

something like this ?

```
var str = Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy,aaaaa,2,0,High Max,22322 //...
var strEnd = str.slice(28).split(/[ ,]+/)
var strStart = str.slice(0,28)
var newStr = strStart + strEnd
```

you could change the slice to the index of 30 instead of 28 im just going off of where you would need to split it at to get the output you mentioned

Comment: this splits High Max into High, Max though. If thats not what you would have to add some more splits or something

Comment: if you are able to put it into object format like { Lorem Ipsum: [array], HIgh Max: [array] } it might be a lot easier